# System.NullReferenceException with Oracle.DataAccess.Client

Tags: oracle, connection, nullreferenceexception

i wrote a ASP.NET application which call a storeed procedure in Oracle 11G
On my system, windows 10 that works perfect, the code to connect look like this:

```
Imports Oracle.DataAccess.Client
Dim s As String = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=myserver)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=orcl)));User Id=HR;Password=test;"

dim oradb as String = s
Dim conn As New OracleConnection
conn.ConnectionString = oradb
conn.Open()
```

When a distribute this to my customer, windows server 2008RS
i get a System.NullReferenceException by conn.open()

For testing a wrote windowsapplication with exactly the same code and that's works fine.

Anybody a idea why it not work as a web application?

Thanks for help
Dani

Comment: Did you install ODP.NET on web server?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

i installed this:
ODAC 12c Release 4 and Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio (12.1.0.2.4)

the same as i installed on my developer machine, this include the odp.net